# Linear Transformation Reflection Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Linear Transformation 
$$T(\vec{x}) =\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0.6&0.8\\0.8&-0.6\\
\end{array}\;\begin{array}{c}\end{array}\right)\vec{x}$$

is a reflection about a line L.

I need to find the equation of the line L(in the form of y = mx)

I was thinking of finding the projection vector but... seems like not working.

Does anybody have any clue? Please help me. Thanks

Comment: What happens to points on the line $L$ when you apply $T$? What does this correspond to in terms of $T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ fixes $L$. A point on $L$ has coordinates $(x,mx)$. Imposing $T(x,mx)=(x,mx)$ gives $m=0,5$